# Unable to print arabic characters on console coming in request in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, encoding, arabic

I am trying to hit request from postman consisting of arabic characters:

`{ "data": "{\"holder passport expiry date\":\"10/09/2021\",\"holder passport issue date\":\"11/09/2011\",\"holder sponsor name\":\"رائد ابو زيدsss\",\"holder occupation code\":8}" }`

While I am trying to print the request in console using logger.info or System.out.println like this:

```
public void printRecord(RequestBodyy requestBody) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody.getData());
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    
    System.out.print(jsonObject.get("holder passport expiry date"));
    
    String str2 = new String("رائد ابو زيدsss");//.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str2);
    String str = new String(jsonObject.get("holder sponsor name").toString());//.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(str);
    
    String data = "{\"eidaID\":\"حسن\"}"; JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data); 
    System.out.println(obj.get("eidaID").toString());
}
```

Output:

```
{"holder sponsor name":"???? ??? ???sss","holder passport expiry date":"10/09/2021","holder occupation code":8,"holder passport issue date":"11/09/2011"}
10/09/2021???? ??? ???sss
???? ??? ???sss
???
```

I am receiving  ???? instead of those arabic characters.

How will I able to do that ?

However, I am able to store these characters in DB coming from API request.

My application.properties :

```
server.port = 8076
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

In pom.xml, I added:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Please help!

Comment: It's mostly a matter of having the correct font.

Comment: Can you please explain ? @user16632363

Comment: Output devices use a font to display characters. If the font you're using doesn't contain a particular character, it can't display it.  In such a case it will generally display some substitute such as a question mark or a 'box' shape.

Comment: How are you receiving this content? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited my question @SotiriosDelimanolis .
Please have a look

Comment: @ShubhamJain check the updated answer and let me know if you still facing issues

Answer (score 0):

try to convert it to a UTF-8 compatible string and then try to print it in console

```
String str = new String("رائد ابو زيدsss".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

now print this string in console or log. You can replace the Arabic string as per your input

===========================================================

**UPDATE 1**

I have done a sample example based on the code you have given. You may change the request processing part as per your need.

**Make sure** you have changed the text file encoding for your **project to UTF-8**. I have used STS (you will get it in Project > Properties)

[image]

**Code**

```
    @RestController
    public class MainController {
        
        @GetMapping(value="/test", consumes = "application/json", produces ="application/json" )
        public void getData(@RequestBody String body) throws 
UnsupportedEncodingException { // I have accepted it as String, you can accept as per your requirement like any Object
            System.out.println("Request Body: " +body);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(body); //This is just to replicate your code
            System.out.print("holder sponsor name: " +jsonObject.get("holder sponsor name"));
        }
    
    }
```

**Request**

[image]

**Result**

```
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.6.0)[0;39m

Request Body: {
    "holder passport expiry date": "10/09/2021",
    "holder passport issue date": "11/09/2011",
    "holder sponsor name": "رائد ابو زيدsss",
    "holder occupation code": 8
}
holder sponsor name: رائد ابو زيدsss
```

Comment: Presumably, this content is coming to them from a request body. They don't have a string they can call `getBytes` one. Or if they do, it's likely already incorrectly decoded.

Comment: Exactly, I am getting the contents from the request. Creating a JSON object from the request. Then, trying to print the keys and values

Comment: This doesn't work in my case.

Comment: It doesn't work in any case of a literal string in Java source code.  The source is in UTF-16 characters by definition; the given code converts it to a UTF-8 byte sequence, and then converts those bytes to UTF-16.  Result, no change.

Comment: check my updated answer